# How to use React's jsx as a replacement of Laravel blade's mail template

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm doing the forgot password and recover password feature using Laravel API and React. I've done the form and now I'm stuck at the backend part.

In the forgotPassword function, it will send a link for recover password at the user's email. But this code `Mail::send('email.forgetPassword',` is a view file for Laravel. How to adjust this part for React? This is my first time doing auth using Laravel hehe.

**Function**

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $request){
        $request->validate(['email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255']]);

        $token = Str::random(64);

        DB::table('password_reset_tokens')->insert([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        Mail::send('email.forgetPassword', ['token' => $token], 
            function($message) use ($request){
                $message->to($request->email);
                $message->subject('Reset Password');
            }
        );

        return response()->json(['message', 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!']);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('forgot-password', [UserController::class, 'forgotPassword'])->name('password.email');
```

**Forgot Password Form**

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    setStatus(null);

    const data = {email};
 
    try {
      await API.get("/api/csrf-cookie").then(async () => {           
        const response = await API.post('/api/forgot-password', data); 
        setStatus(response.data.status);
        if (response.data.error){
          console.log(response.data.error);
          setLoading(false);             
        }
      });          
    } catch (error){
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cant use react's page here since Laravel and React only communicates via api and sends/receives json. You would need to use Laravel's blade to build the mail contents

Answer (score 1):

I can see that in your question you're doing the process manually, while Laravel provides built-in services that you can use to implement this functionality robustly and easily.

Let's take a brief look at the process:

1. **Prepare your authenticatable model(s)**: your authenticatable model(s) (e.g. `App\Models\User`, or any other model that has login capabilities) must implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword` interface, and it should use the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword` trait.
2. **Prepare your routes**: your application must contain 4 basic routes, these routes are as follows:

   1. **password.request**: A `GET` route that returns the view that contains a form in which the user will be asked to enter his E-mail. Since you're using React, you don't need to return any view, so you can leave this route empty, but you must define it nevertheless.
   2. **password.email**: A `POST` route that handles the form submission request, this route will be responsible for validating the email address and sending the password reset request to the corresponding user. Here, sending the reset password link to the user is as easy as calling the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::sendResetLink()` method.
   3. **password.reset**: A `GET` route that will display the reset password form that is displayed when the user clicks the reset password link. This route will receive a token parameter that we will use later to verify the password reset request. Once again, since you're using React, you may leave this route empty, but it must be defined whatsoever.
   4. **password.update**:  A `POST` route that will be responsible for validating the incoming request and updating the user's password in the database.

Notice that you don't need to interact with the `password_reset_tokens` table, Laravel does that automatically.

Regarding your question about the mail template: this is a blade file that gets turned into an E-mail and sent over to the user. In order to do customizations on this template, you should run the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Which will create a new `resources/views/vendor/mail` directory that contains the template files for the mail.

You can learn more about Laravel password reset functionality at: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passwords

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Are you accusing me of using AI to generate this answer? 
I haven't used React, but I've seen developers in action making the password reset login frontend without using Blade, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: my bad I would like to retract my statement. Still OP asked how to use mail template in react's jsx.  Deleted my previous statement.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I'm sorry for the aggressive tone

Comment: No worries, me too. Even I would be like that in your shoes.